# Not able to send email using Swift_Mailer

Tags: php, ubuntu, symfony4, postfix-mta

I am trying to send emails to customers using Postfix which i have installed on DigitalOcean server using the *Swift_Message* and *Swift_SendmailTransport*

I'm able to send a test email using this on the command line.

`echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" myacc@gmail.com`

```
 $transport = new Swift_SendmailTransport('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');
 $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
 $message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
          ->setFrom(['xxx@domain.com' => 'John Doe'])
          ->setTo(['myacc@gmail.com', 'myacc@xxx.co.za' => 'A 
          name'])
          ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
           ;
```

I get nothing from `tail -f /var/log/mail.log`

Comment: Nothing in PHP logs?

Comment: PHP logs? you mean apache log?